# Servicestack, securing traffic

Tags: .net, ssl, servicestack

I have a .Net MVC app thats running under https. And I need that app to call a web service. 
Not a self hosted app.

Im using Servicestack for the web service

How do I secure the the traffic to the web service with SSL

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I secure my service using SSL for Services created using Service stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316804/how-do-i-secure-my-service-using-ssl-for-services-created-using-service-stack)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a web service with SSL than that web service needs to also be hosted under `https` binding. If it is you can just use the `https://` url and call it directly. Otherwise here's a guide on [Configuring SSL with ASP.NET](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HttpBenchmarks#configuring-ssl) or if ServiceStack is self-hosted see this answer on [how to configure a HttpListener Host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14336970/85785).